# LIMIT (0, 1000) phpmyadmin error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, limit

I've had this error :

You have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

However, I changed the maximum number of rows displayed to 1000 (even 10000) and it still gives me an error. I'm using XAMPP and phpmyadmin.

Here's the code I'm trying to run :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS prodaja;

CREATE TABLE prodaja ( id SERIAL, id_stvari BIGINT, id_kupca BIGINT, kvantitet INT, cijena DECIMAL(9,2), podmireno INT );
INSERT INTO prodaja (id_stvari, id_kupca, kvantitet, cijena, podmireno) VALUES (1, 3, 5, 19.95, 0);
INSERT INTO prodaja (id_stvari, id_kupca, kvantitet, cijena, podmireno) VALUES (2, 2, 3, 14.95, 1);
INSERT INTO prodaja (id_stvari, id_kupca, kvantitet, cijena, podmireno) VALUES (3, 1, 1, 29.95, 0);
SELECT * FROM prodaja;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER updateprodaja BEFORE UPDATE ON prodaja
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF ( SELECT podmireno FROM prodaja WHERE id = NEW.id ) > 0 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Ne mogu azurirati red imena podmireno u tablici prodaja';
        END IF;
    END
//
DELIMITER ;

START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE prodaja SET kvantitet = kvantitet + 9 WHERE id = 2;
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM prodaja;
```

What's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not think you can change delimiter within the same SQL query execution using PHPmyadmin... that is why you have to specify it below the query.

Comment: Can you see the words "LIMIT(0,1000)" (or "LIMIT(0,30)" ) in this code? No? Neither can I.

Comment: send me executed query. In which you get error.

Comment: You're just pasting this entire code block in to the SQL window, right? It seems to work fine for me doing that. What phpMyAdmin version do you have?